# Trying to input a parameter into a batch file, getting weird results

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code that I'm working with:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1" == "start" (
    SET /p %CmdLineArgs% =< commandLine.txt
    START C:\edm\NewGenFH60.exe %CmdLineArgs%
 ) ELSE (
    SET /p CmdLineArgs=Command Line Arguments:
    ECHO you typed %CmdLineArgs%
    ECHO %CmdLineArgs% > commandLine.txt
 )
PAUSE
```

When I run this code, the commandLine.txt file gets populated with "ECHO is OFF" and the output is "You typed   ", I'm not sure why.

When I run just this part:

```
SET /p CmdLineArgs=Command Line Arguments:
ECHO you typed %CmdLineArgs%
ECHO %CmdLineArgs% > commandLine.txt
```

in a separate batch file it works as expected, the commandLine.txt file gets populated with whatever I typed in.

The .bat file seems to work when I run it from the cmd line, but not when I click on the .bat file on the desktop. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF "%1"=="start" (
SET /p CmdLineArgs=< commandLine.txt
START C:\edm\NewGenFH60.exe !CmdLineArgs!
) ELSE (
SET /p CmdLineArgs=Command Line Arguments:
ECHO you typed !CmdLineArgs!
ECHO !CmdLineArgs! > commandLine.txt
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you. Do you mind explaining the differences and why yours works and mine doesn't? I tried to up vote your comment but I am new to the forum.

Comment: @Endoro - That's weird. I didn't get the little popup that another user posted an answer, otherwise I wouldn't have posted mine since we said the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DelayedExpansion

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  IF "%1" == "start" (
  SET /p %CmdLineArgs% =< commandLine.txt
  START C:\edm\NewGenFH60.exe %CmdLineArgs%
) ELSE (
  SET /p a=Command Line Arguments: 
  ECHO you typed !a!
  ECHO !a! > commandLine.txt
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind explaining the differences and why yours works and mine doesn't? I tried to up vote your comment but I am new to the forum

Comment: Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx) for a very detailed synopsis